# Is it possible to convert css style tag to javascript object?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm posting this question, with my answer, to help others that may have this problema and to see if others agree with my solution.

Imagine that i have the following HTML doc:

```
<head>
    <style>
        .class1 {
            background-color: white;
            border: "1px dashed black;
        }
        .class2 {
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            border: "1px dashed orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

And now i want to get the following javascript object:

```
{
    .class1: "background-color: white; border: 1px dashed black;",
    .class2: "background-color: dodgerblue; border: 1px dashed orange;"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    var myObject = {};
    var myCss = window.document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var counter = 0; counter < myCss.length; counter++) {
        var thisSelector = myCss[counter].selectorText;
        var thisCss = myCss[counter].style.cssText;
        myObject[thisSelector] = thisCss;
    }
</script>
```

Inspired by John Doherty [link](https://gist.github.com/john-doherty/f9e14202687ee760ef41bf71c989ea54)